# Cut Apache virtual host block

Tags: bash, apache, shell, awk

I'm trying to cut certain virtual host from file which has a lot of them using bash.

Eg. in my script I would like to get virtual host which uses `the_one_known2.example.com`, but another time `the_one_known3.example.com`, namely I would like to get some part form apache config file with beforehand known URL (present in ServerName or ServerAlias) which is set in bash script as a parameter.

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:${SERVER_PORT}>
    ServerName      test1.example.com
    ServerAlias     test2.example.com
    ServerAlias     the_one_known1.example.com
    ServerAlias     test3.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80 *:${SERVER_PORT}>
    ServerName      test4.example.com
    ServerAlias     the_one_known2.example.com
    ServerAlias     test5.example.com
    ServerAlias     test6.example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80 *:${SERVER_PORT}>
    ServerName      the_one_known3.example.com
    ServerAlias     test7.example.com
    ServerAlias     test8.example.com
    ServerAlias     test9.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

So I my URL variable would change to eg. `the_one_known2.example.com` I would get:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:${SERVER_PORT}>
    ServerName      test4.example.com
    ServerAlias     the_one_known2.example.com
    ServerAlias     test5.example.com
    ServerAlias     test6.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

[EDIT]
So far I tried to find first line of a selected virtual host:

```
url_line=$(grep -n -m 1 "${URL}" ./apache.conf" | sed  's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
vitual_host_start_line="$((app_line-1))" // this is an assumption that Virtual Host starts just one line before the first occurance of URL
echo $vitual_host_line // the place it starts
```

But I have a problem to find a last line of this virtual host because it is first occurence of `</VirtualHost>` after `vitual_host_start_line`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -v name="the_one_known2.example.com" 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="</VirtualHost>\n"} $0~name{print; exit}' file
```

I assume `the_one_known2.example.com` is no substring of another domain in your file.

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, **RS**, **ORS**, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS='<VirtualHost[^/]*/' -v ORS="VirtualHost>\n" 'RT~/[[:space:]]+the_one_known2\.example\.com\n/{print RT}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, making RS(record separator) from `<VirtualHost` till next `/` occurrence(non-greedy match). Then checking if it has `[[:space:]]+the_one_known2\.example\.com\n` if yes then print matched value, this will print `VirtualHost>` at ending of passage since its set as ORS value in program.